# Spring cache throws unexpected error for project class

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I am trying to use spring cache. service.getall is called inside the controller. Pagewrapper implement  Serializable and OrganizationListProjection is spring projection. The following are my code

```
@EnableCaching
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
public class SystemApiApplication extends ApplicationConfig {
    ...............
}

@service
public class service{
    @Cacheable("getall")
    public PageWrapper<OrganizationListProjection> getAll() {....}
}
```

when i run, i got following exception

2020-01-27 14:50:39.159 ERROR 30440 --- [-auto-1-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.r
edis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.spr
ingframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor] with root cause

java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1379)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:791)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(LinkedHashMap.java:333)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1416)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:46)
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:35)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:94)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementWriter.write(DefaultRedisElementWriter.java:43)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.write(RedisSerializationContext.java:219)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.serializeCacheValue(RedisCache.java:238)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.put(RedisCache.java:144)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:87)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:783)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:400)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:316)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.microservices.service.OrganizationService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bac57777.getAllOrganization()
        at com.microservices.controller.OrganizationRestController.getAllOrganization(OrganizationRestController.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.MethodExecutionAction.execute(MethodExecutionAction.java:116)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.MethodExecutionAction.executeWithArgs(MethodExecutionAction.java:93)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.MethodExecutionAction.execute(MethodExecutionAction.java:78)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericCommand$1.execute(GenericCommand.java:48)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.AbstractHystrixCommand.process(AbstractHystrixCommand.java:145)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericCommand.run(GenericCommand.java:45)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47)
        at org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextCallable.call(DelegatingSecurityContextCallable.java:87)
        at com.microservices.hystrix.RequestAttributeAwareCallableWrapper$RequestAttributeAwareCallable.call(RequestAttributeAwareCallableWrapper.java:53)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69)
        at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Comment: correction on title. should be projection not project

Comment: If you are going to put a stack trace in, at least format it as code not text, and don't put 100s of lines of it please, you'll get downvoted. It's complaining about Serializing `OrganizationListProjection`, maybe that doesn' t match your Redis table? Maybe it has circular references and you need to put `@Ignore` when returning json, anyway there isn't enough information to answer your question.